# Angular 5 - Call function of child component from parent component

Tags: angular, indexing

I have a little question please:

In my Parent component I have the same child component called 3 times.

```
<div>

   <App-child></App-child>

   <App-child></App-child>

   <App-child></App-child>

<div>
```

In my parent component I would like to call a function that is in the child number 2. (The function is in the 3 child components because they are all the same, how can I please call specifically the one that is in the child 2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your component a local variable

```
<div>

   <App-child></App-child>

   <App-child #theChosenOne></App-child>

   <App-child></App-child>

<div>
```

Get it in your typescript

```
@ViewChild('theChosenOne') theChosenOne: ChildComponent;
```

You can now call it all you want :

```
ngOnInit() { this.theChosenOne.guideUsThroughTheRedSea(); }
```

Comment: Thank you for your super quick answer. The children are called dynamically, so I cannot assign #theChosenOne to them

Comment: Then use `@ViewChildren` on their container !

Comment: I am really sorry, I couldn't implement it, is it please possible to give me an example?

Comment: Well I'm on phone now so it's gonna be though ... [this tutorial might help you though](https://netbasal.com/understanding-viewchildren-contentchildren-and-querylist-in-angular-896b0c689f6e)

Comment: I implemented the ViewChildren, but it is still calling only the function of the first children instead of the second

Comment: Did you select the second one ? :P

Comment: Is it please possible to show me the best way to do it?

Comment: Again, I'm on phone, use the auto completion and the tutorial I gave you !

Comment: @trichetriche Couldn't you just wait until you are off the phone and then respond to the comments with a thoughtful answer?

Comment: @Jim I'm lazy, couch potato POS. More seriously though, I'm on newest questions 99% of my time on SOF, I rarely follow up on a question more than 1 day, unless I'm notified to (again, I would have done it now, but guess what, I'm on the couch watching lucifer, so I'm on phone again)